# Images and css not working with Handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am working on my portfolio and am using handlebars.
I have my main index.js in my root folder. It is working as far as I can tell. My home(index) page loads locally in my browser, but the css and images for it do not load. I also have my views folder, where my layout.hbs and index.hbs is. Then I also have my images/css folders, where I want my index.hbs to find my images/css (which I pass in as parameters in my res.render in my index.js).
However, when I load my home page, I get the errors:

1. "[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (style.css, line 0)"
   &&
2. "[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (resize_profile_pic.jpg, line 0)"

Here is my index.js:

```
// === VARIABLES === //
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var handlebars = require("express-handlebars");
var path = require("path");
var router = express.Router();  //creates a router object, do I even need this???

 //===== view ENGINE SET UP =====//
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.engine(
    "hbs",
    handlebars({
      layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views/layouts"),
      partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, "views/partials"), 
      extname: ".hbs", 
      defaultLayout: "layout" 
    })
);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views")); 
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
//NOT sure what this does??? Or if I need it???
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

//saw this on a previous post but doesn't seem to work???
app.use(express.static('images'));
// Route to display static src images  - also saw this on a previous post???
app.get("/static", (req, res) => {
    res.render("static");
});


//===== .GET PAGES =====//
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {       //also tried app.get, do I need router???
    res.render('index', {title: 'Home Page', css:['style.css']});
});
app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3000);
```

Here is how my image is coded in my index.hbs:

```
<img src="/images/resize_profile_pic.jpg" alt="">
```

*I also tried "images/resize_profile_pic.jpg" and nada.

Comment: Take a look at Express's documentation on serving static assets: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html It indicates that when you specify a virtual path prefix - ie., the first "/public" in `app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));` - that the path for the URI of each assets must begin with that prefix, as in `<img src="/public/images/resize_profile_pic.jpg" alt="">`

Comment: @76484 Hey thanks for the quick reply! So I was reading something about that before I posted my question actually. I tried commenting out the ```app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));``` and using the ```<img src>``` that I have posted, (without the /public/images) and hte images still did not load. I also tired leaving the ```app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));``` in there then adding in the ```"/public"``` to my ```<img src>``` in my hbs and still didn't work....

Comment: Do you have an `images/` folder inside of your `public/` folder and is that where the image file lives?

Comment: So I have my general project stored in a folder called MyPorject, saved on my desktop. Then under the MyProject folder, I have all my subfolders, to include images. I got the public thing from a previous post on StackOverflow, so originally I didn't have it in my code. But regardless, I did not make a public folder. I wasn't sure if it was a default or something.

Comment: It's not a default. Put your `images/` folder in a `public/` folder. Your `express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")` is telling express to serve static assets from a folder in your project called "public". If there isn't a local folder called "public", it's not going to work!

Comment: Okay so should I be putting every subfolder(css, js, html) all inside one big public folder? Inastead could I just scratch the ``` express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")``` and use ```app.use(express.static('images'));``` ? thanks again! Im new to this so trying to figure it all out.

Comment: WIth `app.use(express.static('images'));` you would need to put your subfolders in an `images/` folder. The naming sounds goofy to me; I would much prefer public.

Comment: Okay great that worked to get my css and images to load!! Thanks so much.